# Is there any practical application of Tango Trees?

Tags: algorithm, tree, complexity-theory

[Balanced binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) gives an `O(log(n))` guaranteed search time.

[Tango trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tango_tree) achieves a search of `O(log(log(n))` while compromising small amount of memory per node. While I understand that from theoretical point of view `log(n)` and `log(log(n))` makes a huge difference, for majority of practical applications it provides almost no advantage.

For example even for a huge number like `n = 10^20` (which is like few thousand petabytes) the difference between `log(n) = 64` and `log(log(n)) = 6` is pretty negligible. So is there any practical usage of a Tango tree?

Comment: I wouldn't call one order of magnitude (64/6) "pretty negligible".

Comment: @PaulR this order of magnitude is achieved when you search through 10^20 elements. To get the difference that one can notice (1 second) I need a number way higher then 10^1000.

Comment: It's absolutely negligible if you are dealing with a regular problem. If you are doing some calculations that require worknig with HUGE(REALLY HUGE) numbers then maybe.

Comment: @Chris please look carefully at the question. If you even take the [number of atoms in the universe (n=10^81)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_number) the difference will be negligible `log(n) = 270` and `log(log(n)) = 8`

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr: no, use a splay tree instead.

Tango trees don't give you O(log log n) worst case lookups -- the average case is I think O(log n log log n). What they do is run at most O(log log n) times more slowly than a binary tree with an oracle that performs rotations to optimize the access patterns.

Splay trees might run O(1) times more slowly than the aforementioned theoretical magic tree -- this is the Dynamic Optimality conjecture. Splay trees are much simpler than tango trees and will have lower constant factors to boot. I can't imagine a practical application where the tango tree guarantee would be useful.