# Why is this sorting function returning the object in the wrong order?

Tags: javascript

I came across a challenge in CodeWars and laid out a function that provides my desired results in runJS. The challenge is to correctly sort an array of objects. I used the .sort() method in two ternaries to accomplish my task with the desired results. The problem is that when I run this same function in CW, it returns an output that is totally different than what I'm seeing in runJS and thusly I fail the test. Help? What am I missing? Why is it failing and why am I seeing different results in CW and runJS?

[the variable and the function I am using for CodeWars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6St2r.png)

```
var animal = [
        { name: "Cat", numberOfLegs: 4 }, 
        { name: "Snake", numberOfLegs: 0 }, 
        { name: "Dog", numberOfLegs: 4 },
        { name: "Pig", numberOfLegs: 4 },
        { name: "Human", numberOfLegs: 2 },
        { name: "Bird", numberOfLegs: 2 }];

function sortAnimal(animal) {
  let legs = animal.sort((a, b) => a.numberOfLegs < b.numberOfLegs ? -1 : 1);
  return legs.sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name && a.numberOfLegs === b.numberOfLegs ? -1 : 1);
}
```

[the output for this function in runJS, which is also the solution for CW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gl0P.png)

```
sortAnimal(animal)
// output:
[
  { name: 'Snake', numberOfLegs: 0 },
  { name: 'Bird', numberOfLegs: 2 },
  { name: 'Human', numberOfLegs: 2 },
  { name: 'Cat', numberOfLegs: 4 },
  { name: 'Dog', numberOfLegs: 4 },
  { name: 'Pig', numberOfLegs: 4 }
]
```

[the error I receive in CodeWars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dSt4.png)

```
//the test:
describe("Animal sorting test", function(){
  it("", function(){
      var animal = [
        { name: "Cat", numberOfLegs: 4 }, 
        { name: "Snake", numberOfLegs: 0 }, 
        { name: "Dog", numberOfLegs: 4 },
        { name: "Pig", numberOfLegs: 4 },
        { name: "Human", numberOfLegs: 2 },
        { name: "Bird", numberOfLegs: 2 }];
     
     Test.assertSimilar( sortAnimal(animal),[{ name: 'Snake', numberOfLegs: 0 }, { name: 'Bird', numberOfLegs: 2 }, { name: 'Human', numberOfLegs: 2 }, { name: 'Cat', numberOfLegs: 4 }, { name: 'Dog', numberOfLegs: 4 }, { name: 'Pig', numberOfLegs: 4 }], "");

  });
});

Expected: '[{ name: \'Snake\', numberOfLegs: 0 }, { name: \'Bird\', numberOfLegs: 2 }, { name: \'Human\', numberOfLegs: 2 }, { name: \'Cat\', numberOfLegs: 4 }, { name: \'Dog\', numberOfLegs: 4 }, { name: \'Pig\', numberOfLegs: 4 }]', 
instead got: '[{ name: \'Cat\', numberOfLegs: 4 }, { name: \'Dog\', numberOfLegs: 4 }, { name: \'Pig\', numberOfLegs: 4 }, { name: \'Bird\', numberOfLegs: 2 }, { name: \'Human\', numberOfLegs: 2 }, { name: \'Snake\', numberOfLegs: 0 }]'
```

Comment: The sort function seems to be working fine, but the codewars assert is taking the original value of the animal array for some reason

Comment: JS on CodeWars runs in node.js which uses the Google Chrome V8 JS engine. As your sort is incorrect, it can result in different order on different browsers.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks so much! Even though runJS said I was correct, I was far from it!!!

Comment: @Slai Thank you! Can you recommend some type of similar javascript 'scratchpad' that I can work out functions on, or some other process you recommend to get accurate results?

Comment: If your comparators are written correctly, you won't expose implementation details in different sorting functions across versions of JS (CW uses Node 8 in this challenge which is pretty outdated). This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671125/why-does-sorting-a-js-array-of-numbers-with-work/) might help show how an invalid sort that isn't taking into account all possible comparator return values (less than 0, 0 and greater than zero) can give you weird results on different implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sorts are not considering equal values that should return zero.

For numeric sorts this is simplified by using subtraction which will either return negative, positive or zero when equal.

You also aren't addressing the alphabetical sort of names for equal leg counts.

First check if legs are the same and if so return the alpha sort of the names, otherwise return the legs difference

```js
function sortAnimal(animal) {
  return animal.sort((a,b)=>{
     if(a.numberOfLegs === b.numberOfLegs){
         // when legs are same sort by the names
         return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
     }
     return a.numberOfLegs - b.numberOfLegs
  });  
}

const sorted = sortAnimal(animal)
console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted))

const isMatch =  sorted.every((el,i)=> Object.keys(el).every(k=> el[k] === expected[i][k]))
console.log('matches expected:', isMatch)
```

```html
<script>
var animal=[{name:"Cat",numberOfLegs:4},{name:"Snake",numberOfLegs:0},{name:"Dog",numberOfLegs:4},{name:"Pig",numberOfLegs:4},{name:"Human",numberOfLegs:2},{name:"Bird",numberOfLegs:2}];
const expected=[{name:"Snake",numberOfLegs:0},{name:"Bird",numberOfLegs:2},{name:"Human",numberOfLegs:2},{name:"Cat",numberOfLegs:4},{name:"Dog",numberOfLegs:4},{name:"Pig",numberOfLegs:4}];
</script>
```

Comment: @charlieftl thanks for taking the time to explain. I was checking my answers in runJS, but that seems as if it's prone to misleading answers. Is there a process or app you prefer for checking your code as you chip away - anything you might recommend for a fledgeling dev? Thanks again!

Comment: Shouldn't matter, results should be same regardless of environment used to run the code. I disagree with the comment made that the sorts could be different so long as you do the sort properly which means also considering equal conditions. For quick scratch pad I like using repl.it

Answer (score 0):

Sort conditions can be chained with `||` operator, as comparison equality should result in [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) 0:

```js
const animal = [ { name: "Cat",   numberOfLegs: 4 }, 
                 { name: "Snake", numberOfLegs: 0 }, 
                 { name: "Dog",   numberOfLegs: 4 }, 
                 { name: "Pig",   numberOfLegs: 4 },
                 { name: "Human", numberOfLegs: 2 }, 
                 { name: "Bird",  numberOfLegs: 2 } ]

const sortAnimal = a => a.sort((a, b) => a.numberOfLegs - b.numberOfLegs 
                                      || a.name.localeCompare(b.name))

console.log( JSON.stringify( sortAnimal(animal) ).replace(/},/g, "},\n ") )
```